# Rowsums giving inf value where it shouldn't

Tags: r

I'm working on an assignment in R where we have to compare different NBA player stats and determine who is the most valuable player, and when I divide two datasets and call `rowsums` to add show what the highest value is, the value for two of the players comes up as `Inf`.

[image: screenshot of rstudio project]

Comment: Hi Connor! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could run dput(df) or dput(head(df)), and edit your question to add the results into it, that would be great thanks !

Comment: As Mark says, you need to post your data.  From your screenshot a likely culprit is division by zero.